# Find element and select option with phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to find an element by `name` and select an option from a drop-down menu by `value` with `phantomjs`. The following script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org/")

select = Select(webdriver.find_element_by_name("language"))
select.select_by_value("es")

html_doc = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

generate the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    select = Select(webdriver.find_element_by_name("language"))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'
```

If I change `webdriver.PhantomJS()` I to `webdriver.Firefox()` I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? The module is not correctly installed?

Answer (score 1):

`webdriver` is the module name you have imported, while `driver` is your WebDriver instance.

Change

```
select = Select(webdriver.find_element_by_name("language"))
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("language"))
                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: @CptNemo: Do you have feedback on this? Run the code above, you should be all good.